# What does "be proactively available to help others" mean?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

- Actively going to others to provide help even if they don't need it?
- Being available actively to help others whenever they need it?
- Or something else?

Comment: The number of Google hits for "proactively available" -"produce a schedule of any fees" is too small to claim it is in common usage.

Comment: I think it means asking other people if they need any help instead of making them come to you. However, this sounds a bit like business-speak (let me guess, you found it on a job posting or in an employee handbook?), so it's a bit puffed-up.

Comment: What @Kevin said. It's just biz-speak for *actively **offer** help* and/or *actively **make people aware** that you are available **if** they need help.*

Comment: @KevinWorkman Such up-puffery can also be found in resumés.

Answer (score 2):

To "be proactively available to help others" means the author wanted to insert the term "proactive," a positive term in managerial circles, into a phrase where it is unnecessary. The phrase is perfectly clear if you render it "be available to help others." The term "proactive," in this phrase, adds nothing.

Comment: Less than nothing.  You can't force (proactively) and wait (be available) at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

This phrase doesn't make any sense to me. It's controversial. You're either available and thus passively waiting for being addressed for help; or you're proactively assisting people.

Comment: do you mean contradictory instead of controversial?

Answer (score 0):

I think the first explanation you provided makes the most sense. Being *proactive* involves solving problems in a preventive manner. Being *available to help others* involves setting aside some time that you plan to spend helping other people with something. So, being *proactively available* means setting aside more time than you think you will actually need. During that time you will be planning to help others.